# Django key word filter sentance

Tags: django, filter, django-filter

I have a keyword class that links to something, I am trying to create a filter so you can pass in a sentence and it will find the key words in the sentence.
tags-keywords/?description=these young people are annoying

The TagTrigger would look like this:
trigger = young people (CharField)

I wondered if there was any way to do this in the Django ORM.

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    description = self.request.GET.get('description')

    if description:
        qs = qs.filter(keyword__whatever=description)

    return qs
```

Thanks

Comment: please rephrase your question with more detail

Comment: I have now rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
qs = super().get_queryset()
description = self.request.GET.get('description')

if description:
    qs = qs.filter(keyword__contains=description)

return qs
```

here contains are called lookups, you can find all possible in docs below,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#id4

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this myself by annotating the query:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    description = self.request.GET.get('description')

    if description:
        qs = qs.annotate(description=Value(description, output_field=CharField()))
        qs = qs.filter(description__icontains=F('keyword'))

    return qs
```